# Running mc (midnight commander) under su on Mojave/Catalina/Big Sur/Monterey

Tags: macos, sudo, root

After installing prebuild mc binary to Mojave and newer ([link](https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/Binaries) and [link 2](http://kr0leg.livejournal.com/7628.html)), and trying to run mc under root with sudo command, I got error:

```
$sudo mc
common.c unimplemented subshell type 1
read (subshell_pty...): No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears that mc requires to match precompiled shell version, e.g. /bin/bash to be the one.

In order to resolve this, its is required to change default root shell from sh to bash, and do it with following command:

```
sudo dscl . -change /Users/root UserShell /bin/sh /bin/bash
```

To revert back in case you have some problems, just reverse the parameters:

```
sudo dscl . -change /Users/root UserShell /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Just in case above commands do not work, may be default shell was already changed. Check it with command:

```
dscl . -read /Users/root UserShell
```

Hope it will save tons of time for you.

Comment: Great! That works. Is there any known reason to not keep this change permanent?

Comment: I keep it, as I am used to bash

Answer (score -1):

Midnight Commander is still actively developed. But this default shell bug has been ongoing for years. Apple switched Catalina to use zsh but default /bin/sh is still there for backwards compatibility of bourne shell scripts. Other OSes are impacted by this shell issue. Some use the Dash shell to be /bin/sh, etc.

Newer console file managers such as lf, ranger, broot, vifm, nnn, fff, etc., etc., etc. are worth a look.